# MongoDB - wiping sensitive data (documents) securely/permanently so that it cannot be recovered

Tags: mongodb

Say some sensitive data is saved as documents in MongoDB Database which we want to erase securely/permanently so that it cannot be recovered and misused by anyone.
Using remove function on some documents does not permanently delete the data. It can still be recovered. How to permanently delete the data and make sure that this data cannot be recovered. 
What should be done apart from remove function.
We have to delete the data selectively.

Comment: Hi,please specify recovered by someone else?

Answer (score 1):

There are many steps and cycles to what, I think, you are asking. Due to the nature of how a hard disk works this is impossible within MongoDB itself.

MongoDB will remove the rows from the DB itself so they cannot be recovered by anoyne on the website end etc or even by querying the database from within the server however the data does still exist on the hard disk itself.

Basically the data, when using `remove()`, will not be visible by normal means. This data will normally (should) be hidden from the OS itself.

To "remove" this fully you will need software that can overwrite that area of the disk multiple times (maybe 3000 times) with a secure (probably military grade) algorithm designed to induce full bleeding across the rings to prevent microscopic recovery of the data via reading the disk physically.

This is normally either a botted or manual process when hard disks go into end of life cycle. I personally like: http://www.dban.org/